# Wrong optimal solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, simplex

If we have a linear programming problem that is of the form as the following:

[image]

The initial tableau is the following:

[image]

Then we get this:

$\begin{matrix}
B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & \theta & \\ 
P_1 & 11 & 1 & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & 1 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 &  &L_1'=L_1+ \frac{1}{2}L_2' \\ 
P_2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &  & L_2'=\frac{L_2}{2}\\ 
P_6 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 &  &L_3'=L_3 \\ 
 & z & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 &0  &  & L_4'=L_4+2L_2'
\end{matrix}$

Any of $P_3, P_4, P_5$ we choose the solution that we will get will be non-degenerate, right?

I chose $P_3$ and I got the following tableau:

$\begin{matrix}
B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 &  & \theta\\ 
P_3 & \frac{44}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 0 & 1 & \frac{4}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 11 &L_1''=\frac{L_1' 4}{3} \\ 
P_2 & \frac{22}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 1 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & \frac{2}{3} & 0 & 11 & L_2''=L_2'+\frac{1}{2}L_1''\\ 
P_6 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 4 &L_3''=L_3' \\ 
 &z  & -\frac{5}{3} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{8}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 &  & L_4''=L_4'-2L_1''
\end{matrix}$

$-\frac{5}{3}>-\frac{8}{3}$, thus $P_4$ gets in the basis and $P_6$ gets out of the basis.

Then I got the following tableau:

$\begin{matrix}
B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 &  & \theta\\ 
P_3 & \frac{28}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{2}{4} & \frac{28}{4} &L_1'''=L_1''-\frac{4}{3}L_3'' \\ 
P_2 & \frac{14}{3} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & - & L_2'''=L_2''-\frac{2}{3}L_3'''\\ 
P_4 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & - &L_3'''=\frac{L_3''}{2} \\ 
 &z  & -\frac{5}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{4}{3} &  & L_4'''=L_4''+\frac{8}{3}L_3'''
\end{matrix}$

Then $P_1$ gets in the basis and $P_3$ gets out of the basis:

$\begin{matrix}
B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 &  & \theta\\ 
P_1 & \frac{28}{4} & 1 & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} &  &L_1''''=\frac{L_1''' 3}{4} \\ 
P_2 & \frac{14}{3} & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} &  & L_2''''=L_2'''\\ 
P_4 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & - &L_3''''=L_3''' \\ 
 &z  & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{4} & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{3}{4} &  & L_4''''=L_4'''+\frac{5}{3}L_1''''
\end{matrix}$

Is everything right?

If so, do we deduce now from the fact that $z_k''''-c_k \geq 0 \forall k$ and that we have a non-degenerate basic feasible solution, that it is the optimal one?

But the optimal solution should be equal to $-7$. Are the values of one of the tableaus wrong?

**EDIT**: I found this now in my textbook:

**Degenerate solutions**:

- Obviously if $\theta_0=\min_i \left\{ \frac{x_{i0}}{x_{ij}}: x_{ij}>0\right\}$ is achieved in more than one rows ( for example $\theta_0=\frac{x_{10}}{x_{1j}}=\frac{x_{20}}{x_{2j}}$), then the corresponding solution $x_1$ is  degenerate.
- If the initial solution is degenerate , then we might have had $x_{10}=0, x_{1j}>0$, thus $\theta_0=0$ and therefore $x_1=x_0$ and $z_1=z_0$, i.e. that the solution couldn't be improved.

At both of the above cases, we turn the degenerate solution to non-degenerate, replacing $0$ of the basic variable by $\epsilon>0$, arbitrarily small and we continue normally till we find the optimal solution, and then we set again $\epsilon=0$.

If we do this, will we get a different tableau?

Comment: The solution $x_1=7$ and $x_4=4$ looks right. Therefore $z^*=-7$. You are finish with the simplex algorithm if all $c_j\geq 0$. But at the simplex algorithm you usually introduce an artificial variable if you have an equality as a constraint. Thus $a_1,a_2$ and $a_3$ are missing.

Comment: @callculus Could you explain it further to me? Why do we have to introduce an artificial variable in this case where we just have equalities?

Comment: If you apply the simplex algorithm you always introduce a artificial variable for every $=$- and $\geq$-constraint. This is the algorithm. In the case of a $\geq$-constraint you additional have a negative slack variable.

Comment: If we have  equalities we don't have to introduce artificial variables. So why do we have to indruce one in this case? @callculus

Comment: That is not  true. See here: https://www3.nd.edu/~dgalvin1/30210/30210_F07/presentations/simplex_full.pdf

Comment: See also here: http://www.unc.edu/depts/stat-or/courses/provan/STOR614_web/lect05_revised.pdf and here http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/9434/9660836/online_tutorials/heizer10e_tut3.pdf

Comment: @callculus According to my notes, a linear programming problem in canonical form is as follows:

$$ \pm \max (c_1 x_1+ \dots+ c_n x_n) \\ Ax=b , A \in M^{m \times n} ,  \\ r(A)=m<n \\ x=(x_1, \dots, x_n), b=(b_1, \dots, b_m) \\ x_i \geq 0, i=1, \dots, n \\ b_j \geq 0, j=1, \dots, m $$

Comment: That´s not wrong. But if you apply the simplex method to your problem, you must add an artificial variable  (=- and $\geq$-constraints). You get the equalities by introducing slack and surplus variables for $\leq$- and $\geq$-constraints.

Comment: In this case , the matrix that corresponds to the given equations contains the identity matrix. So why do we have to introduce an artificial variable? Because the initial solution is degenerate? Or is there an other reason? @callculus

Comment: @callculus But $x_2 = \frac{14}{3}$, so the objective function value can't be $-7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staring form the tableau with basis $P_3,P_2,P_4$, some entries are incorrect.
In the tableau with basis $P_3,P_2,P_4$, the entry at column $P_1$ row $P_2$ should be $\frac23$ instead of $0$.

You may verify the GNU Octave code [online](http://octave-online.net).

```
format rat;
c = [-1 2 -3 0 0 0]'; b = [11 0 8]';
A = [
1 -.5 1 1 0 0;
0 2 -1 0 1 0;
0 0 0 2 0 1];
basis = [3 2 6]; B = A(:,basis); cB = c(basis);
T = [B\b B\A; 0 cB'*(B\A)-c']
T =

   44/3        4/3          0          1        4/3        1/3          0
   22/3        2/3          1          0        2/3        2/3          0
      8          0          0          0          2          0          1
      0       -5/3          0          0       -8/3        1/3          0
basis = [3 2 4]; B = A(:,basis); cB = c(basis);
T = [B\b B\A; 0 cB'*(B\A)-c']
T =

   28/3        4/3          0          1          0        1/3       -2/3
   14/3        2/3          1          0          0        2/3       -1/3
      4          0          0          0          1          0        1/2
      0       -5/3          0          0          0        1/3        4/3
basis = [1 2 4]; B = A(:,basis); cB = c(basis);
T = [B\b B\A; 0 cB'*(B\A)-c']
T =

      7          1          0        3/4          0        1/4       -1/2
      0          0          1       -1/2          0        1/2          0
      4          0          0          0          1          0        1/2
      0          0          0        5/4          0        3/4        1/2
```

Thererfore, the optimal solution is $(7,0,0,4,0,0)^T$, with an optimal value of $-7+2(0)-3(0) = -7$.

---

The degeneracy of the BFS and its optimality are two different things.  Let me use [an *adapted* example in another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1594699/290189) to illustrate this.

$\max y$ subject to

\begin{align}
\color{blue}{x+y}&\le\color{blue}{1}\\
\color{red}x\phantom{+y}&\le\color{red}1\\
x,y&\ge0
\end{align}

[image: a degenerate LPP]

Obviously, exactly one of the blue and red constraints is *redundant*, so this LPP has degenerate solution.

We transform it to the standard form by adding slack variable $\color{blue}{s_1}, \color{red}{s_2}$.

$\max x$ subject to

\begin{align}
\color{blue}{x+y+s_1\phantom{+s_2}}&=\color{blue}{1}\\
\color{red}{x\phantom{+y+s_1}+s_2}&=\color{red}1\\
x,y,\color{blue}{s_1},\color{red}{s_2}&\ge0
\end{align}

Thus, each of $x=0,y=0,\color{blue}{s_1=0},\color{red}{s_2=0}$ corresponds to a line which bounds the feasible region.  If we choose $x,y$ as basic variables, then the basic solution is $x_B=(x,y)=(1,0)$, and we calculate the simplex tableau at this degenerate point.

```
format rat;
c = [0 1 0 0]'; b = [1 1]'; A = [1 1 1 0; 1 0 0 1];
basis = [1 2]; B = A(:,basis); cB = c(basis);
T = [B\b B\A; cB'*(B\b) cB'*(B\A) - c']
T =

          1          1          0          0          1
         -0         -0          1          1         -1
          0          0          0          1         -1
```

Therefore, the simplex tableau is

\begin{array}{c|r|rrrr|r}
  B & b & x & y & s_1 & s_2 & \theta \\ \hline
  x & 1 & 1 & 0 &   0 & 1^* &      1 \\
  y & 0 & 0 & 1 &   1 &  -1 &      - \\ \hline
  z & 0 & 0 & 0 &   1 &  -1 &
\end{array}

**We are *not* trapped in the degenerate solution.**  Therefore, $x$ leaves the basis and $\color{red}{s_2}$ enters the basis.

```
basis = [4 2]; B = A(:,basis); cB = c(basis);
T = [B\b B\A; cB'*(B\b) cB'*(B\A) - c']
T =

          1          1          0          0          1
          1          1          1          1          0
          1          1          0          1          0
```

Therefore, the simplex tableau is

\begin{array}{c|r|rrrr|r}
B & b & x & y & s_1 & s_2 & \theta \\ \hline
  s_2 & 1 & 1 & 0 &   0 &   1 &      - \\
y & 1 & 1 & 1 &   1 &   0 &      - \\ \hline
z & 1 & 1 & 0 &   1 &   0 &
\end{array}

---

I *don't* think that "replacing $0$ of the basic variable by $\epsilon > 0$" is meaningful.

Suppose that "the initial solution is degenerate, then we might have had $x_{10}=0, x_{1j}>0$, thus $\theta_0=0$ and therefore $x_1=x_0$ and $z_1=z_0$, i.e. that the solution can't be improved".  Then congratulations, you have found the *optimal* degenerate solution, if you *aren't* [trapped in a cycle](http://people.orie.cornell.edu/miketodd/or630/SimplexCyclingExample.pdf) with negative entries on the last row.

I'll now demonstrate "turning the degenerate solution to non-degenerate, replacing $0$ of the basic variable by $\epsilon>0$".

We have this simplex tableau.

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{c|r|r|rr|r}
     B &    c_B &      b &    P_1 &          P_j & \theta \\ \hline
   P_1 &      * &      0 & \cdots & x_{1j} (> 0) &      0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots &       \vdots & \vdots \\ \hline
       &      z &  \star & \cdots &    z_j - c_j &
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Replace $0$ by $\epsilon$.

\begin{equation*}
  \begin{array}{c|r|r|rr|r}
       B &    c_B &        b &    P_1 &          P_j &          \theta \\ \hline
     P_1 &      * & \epsilon & \cdots & x_{1j} (> 0) & \epsilon/x_{1j} \\
  \vdots & \vdots &   \vdots & \ddots &       \vdots &          \vdots \\ \hline
         &      z &    \star & \cdots &    z_j - c_j &
  \end{array}
\end{equation*}

Therefore, the new objective function value is

\begin{equation*}
  z' = \star - \frac{z_j - c_j}{x_{1j}} \epsilon.
\end{equation*}

If $z_j - c_j < 0$, **you've improved the objective function value by $\dfrac{c_j - z_j}{x_{1j}} \color{red}{\epsilon}$**, and you still have an arbitrarily small number $\epsilon/x_{1j}$ in the first row.  Therefore, *I don't understand what's the point of replacing $0$ by $\epsilon$*.

Comment: Is it necessary to replace $0$ of the basic variable by $\epsilon>0$ ? $$$$
Also I get other values of $z_0-c_0$. At the last tableau, I get it equal to $-7$ and at the other previous one $-\frac{56}{3}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Evinda I'm editing my answer.  <del>Which one are you referring to?  Where you do get $-\frac{56}{3}$?</del>  You're right for the values of $z_0 - c_0 = c_B x_B$, which can be calculated by `cB'*(B\b)`.  Btw, I don't understand the point of "replacing $0$ of the basic variable by $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: The last tableau that I got is this one: $\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & \theta & \\ 
P_1 &  -1& 7 & 1 & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} &  & L_1''''=L_1''' \frac{3}{4}\\ 
P_2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 &  & L_2''''=L_2'''-\frac{2}{3}L_1''''\\ 
P_4 & 0 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 &1  & 0 & \frac{1}{2} &  & L_3''''=L_3'''\\ 
 & z & -7 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{4} & 0 & \frac{3}{4} & \frac{1}{2} &  & L_4''''=L_4'''+\frac{5}{3}L_1'''' 
\end{matrix}$ $$$$
and the previous tableau at the last row where -7 is, I had found $-\frac{56}{3}$.

Comment: According to the textbook, we can replace at the intitial solution $(11,0,0,0,0,8)$ , the $0$ that corresponds to $x_5$ by $\epsilon$ and then apply the simplex method. Then at the last tableau we replace $\epsilon $ by $0$ and get the solution. But this isn't necessary, isn't it?

Comment: @Evinda Yes, your tableau is correct.  I'm going to edit my answer again and explain why "replacing $\epsilon$ by $0$" is pointless.

Comment: @Evinda Why is there a need to replace $0$ by $\epsilon$?  Here `basis = [1 5 6]`.

\begin{array}{c|r|r|rrrrrr|r}
    B & c_B &   b & P_1 &  P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & \theta \\ \hline
  P_1 &  -1 &  11 &   1 & -1/2 &   1 &   1 &   0 &   0 &     11 \\
  P_5 &   0 &   0 &   0 &    2 &  -1 &   0 &   1 &   0 &      - \\
  P_6 &   0 &   8 &   0 &    0 &   0 & 2^* &   0 &   1 &      4 \\ \hline
      &   z & -11 &   0 & -3/2 &   2 &  -1 &   0 &   0 &
\end{array}

Therefore, $x_6$ is replaced by $x_4$.

Comment: \begin{array}{c|r|r|rrrrrr|r}
    B & c_B &  b & P_1 &  P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 &  P_6 & \theta \\ \hline
  P_1 &  -1 &  7 &   1 & -1/2 &   1 &   0 &   0 & -1/2 &      - \\
  P_5 &   0 &  0 &   0 &  2^* &  -1 &   0 &   1 &    0 &      0 \\
  P_4 &   0 &  4 &   0 &    0 &   0 &   1 &   0 &  1/2 &      - \\ \hline
      &   z & -7 &   0 & -3/2 &   2 &   0 &   0 &  1/2 &
\end{array}

And you can get the optimal tableau in the question without the need to introduce $\epsilon$.

Comment: I get a different tableau given the basis [1 5 6]:$\begin{matrix}
B & c_B & b & P_1 & P_2 & P_3 & P_4 & P_5 & P_6 & \theta & \\ 
P_1 & -1 & 11 & 1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & - & L_1 \\ 
P_5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & -1 & 0 & 1& 0 & 0 &L_2\\ 
P_6 & 0& 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 & - & L_3\\ 
 & z & 0 & 1 & -2 & 3 & 0&0 &0  &  & L_4
\end{matrix}$ and the base [1 5 4] doesn't appear. Am I wrong?

Comment: Also could you explain to me how we deduce that (7,0,0,4,0,0) gives the optimal solution although we have again a 0 at the column of b, i.e. a degenerate solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34089/discussion-between-gnu-supporter-and-evinda).